# Como passar variáveis vindas de post, guardá-las até à ultimo step e mostrar todos os valores

Tags: codeigniter, variáveis, view, controller

Tenho um formulário que está dividido em 10 partes, ou seja, vou guardando via post as variáveis de página para página. No entanto, caso faça refresh na página todas as variáveis anteriores são perdidas.

Como posso resolver o problema?

**Esquema:**
Fase 1 - fase1_view -> Post -> fase1controller -> loadview_fase2
Fase 2 - fase2_view -> variaveis_fase1 (input hidden)-> post-> fase2controller-> loadview_fase3 (envia todas as variaveis guardadas para a fase3)
Fase 3 - fase3_view -> variaveis_fase_1_e_2 (input hidden) -> post -> fase3controller -> loadview_fase_4 (envia todas as variaveis guardadas até ao momento para a view da fase 4)
.
.
.

Por ai em diante... Mas caso faça um refresh à página, todas as variáveis são perdidas.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sessões, armazene cada etapa em uma array com os dados e coloque na sessão separado cada etapa por uma chave principal, exemplo:

```
$array = array(
    'etapa 1' => array(),
    'etapa 2' => array(),
    'etapa 3' => array()
);

$this->session->set_userdata($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes gravar a informação usando php em base de dados ou então podes guardar em **cookies**

Deixa me mostrar-te um exemplo:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

O que eu faria seria, a cada passo ia guardando a informação em **cookies** então no fim do formulario quando tiveres de guardar a informação em base de dados ou enviar por e-mail eu iria buscar essa informação às **cookies**

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

```
setcookie($nome_para_a_variavel_cookie, $variavel_com_conteudo_aguardar_nesta_cookie, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
```